# How to specify assembly description in an SDK-style project?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, winui-3

I am developing an unpackaged WinUI 3 app. I can't seem to be able to set the "Description" field in the assembly properties dialog. Setting the project's `<Description>` tag does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must set the [GenerateAssemblyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#generateassemblyinfo) attribute to false in your project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>WinUIAppFx</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>
    ...  
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    ...  
  
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

And then you can define the assembly attributes somewhere in a code file, like this with C#:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("My Title")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("My Product")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright (C) 2022 My Company. All rights reserved.")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("5.6.7.8")]
```

This is what you'll get (for the .NET .dll and the native host .exe):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `AssemblyTitle` tag. Don't know, why .NET is not using the `Description` tag.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <AssemblyTitle>Your File Description</AssemblyTitle>
    ...  
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```